# ColdFusion BB codes

Tags: coldfusion

I would like to translate some values in the comments section in my posts to HTML. So, in fact, I want to translate values in (*CFOUTPUT*) `#comments#` such as `[b]`, `[/b]`, `[i]` and `[/i]` to their HTML counterparts. I have no idea how I should do this though, and that is why I'm asking help on Stackoverflow.

My best guess is to achieve this by using the `RePlace` function, but I have no idea how.

(Posted from comments)

```
<cfoutput>#REReplace(gettopic.text,"[b]","<b>","ALL")#</cfoutput>     
<cfoutput>#REReplace(gettopic.text,"[/b]","</b>","ALL")#</cfoutput> 
<cfoutput>#REReplace(gettopic.text,"[i]","<i>","ALL")#</cfoutput> 
<cfoutput>#REReplace(gettopic.text,"[/i]","</i>","ALL")#</cfoutput>
```

Can't do anything else as I don't understand how to combine

Comment: Try the replace() function with [b], see how it turns out.

Comment: Which part of doing a string replace are you having trouble with? If you have *no idea*, perhaps start with reading the docs? You must have *some idea* after that..? https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Replace https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ReplaceList https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/REReplace

Comment: Works great @DanBaruck, but the problem starts (@AdamCameron) when I'm adding more `BB codes`, as Coldfusion only replaces the first BB code that I specified, it ignores all the others. And whoops, my bad, added the MySQL tag without even remembering it.

Comment: Post some code. Also (and I don't mean to be patronising when I say this)... step BACK from the code for 5min and think through what you need to do to replace either ALL the codes or EACH code in turn, depending on the approach you take. After 5min... update your question with the code you're trying . Start with a simple string and work your way up to more complicated ones as you work through. Prove each line of approach before moving onto the next.

Comment: `replace()` has an attribute to replace all occurrences. Did you look at the docs like @AdamCameron suggested?

Comment: I looked at the docs, and I still can't figure it out what I need to place after the `string` when using the `REReplace` function. For example, this code is just crappy that I've created, but I have no idea how to really make it working:

`<cfoutput>#REReplace(gettopic.text,"[b]","<b>","ALL")#</cfoutput> 
<cfoutput>#REReplace(gettopic.text,"[/b]","</b>","ALL")#</cfoutput>
`

The second problem is that the docs don't explain how to replace multiple tags, for example, I would like `[b]` to be translated into `<b>`, `[/b]` into `</b>`, `[i]` into `<i>` and `[/i]` into `</i>`, and nothing else.

Comment: The simplest way is to run the replace function 4 times, once each for each opening and closing bold and italic tag.  However, since these are html tags, the result of your work will not be clear on  a web page.  If you simply output onto the page, you'll have to look at the html source to verify your work.  Other alternatives are to output into a <pre> </pre> block, or, my personal favourite, into a textarea.

Comment: @DanBaruck Thanks! But the problem is that I'm getting individual results, but I want to combine all of the `REReplace` functions to only just one.

Comment: @Yannick post what you've tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty obvious you haven't read much of the docs as they would have told you what you're doing wrong, but I'll go ahead and spare everyone elses time.

You need to set a variable and then clean *that* variable rather than just outputting your original string. You would be well served checking out this [tutorial](http://www.learncfinaweek.com/week1/Setting_Variables/) which explains how to set a variable or really any general programming tutorial as this is extremely basic stuff . Something you would learn the first day of class or the first section of a tutorial

```
<cfset cleanString = replace(gettopic.text,"[b]","<b>","ALL")>
<cfset cleanString = replace(cleanString,"[/b]","</b>","ALL")>
<cfset cleanString = replace(cleanString,"[i]","<i>","ALL")> 
<cfset cleanString = replace(cleanString,"[/i]","</i>","ALL")> 
<cfoutput>
  #cleanString#
</cfoutput>
```

You can also use the `replaceList` function

```
<cfset cleanString = replaceList(gettopic.text,'[b],[/b],[i],[/i]','<b>,</b>,<i>,</i>')>
<cfoutput>
  #cleanString#
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll check out the tutorial, and recheck the docs because I couldn't find anything on combining multiple replacements.